# Thinking-Sphinx Grouping Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, thinking-sphinx

I have have the meeting model which belongs to the project:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :meetings
end

class Meeting < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project

  define_index do
    join project

    indexes agenda
    indexes project.name. :as => :project_name
  end 
end
```

I attempt to search with grouping:

```
Meeting.search("stuff", :group_by => 'project_id', :group_function => :attr)
```

I get the following error:

```
group-by attribute 'project_id' not found
```

Any suggestions?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a wild guess based on the examples in the ThinkingSphinx docs (http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/searching.html#grouping), but perhaps you need to include the attribute to be grouped by in the indexing.

Try adding `has project_id` to your `define_index`.